# how to display the dynamic data in html page

Tags: python, django, web

how to send data to club.html dynamically changing with user.

how to achieve this. I stuck here.

I don't know where is the mistake please help me.

[image: reference image]

club.html

```
<div class='container'>
            <p class="newlycreated">Prisimax Welcomes you {{user.username}}
            <img src={{user.userprofile.userphoto.url}} id="ownimg"></p>
            <br>
            <p style="margin-left: 100px;">Your LEVEL: {{Clubmember.level}} </p>
            <p style="margin-left: 100px;">Your cash <i class="fas fa-wallet"></i> : {{Clubmember.usermoney}}</p>
        </div>
```

views.py

```
class club(View):
    template_name = "club.html"
    def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.request.user.userprofile.Isclubmem:
            club_member = Clubmember.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.userprofile)
            context = {
                'club_member': club_member
            }
            return render(self.request,'club.html',context=context)
        return render(self.request,'club.html')
    def post(self, *args ,**kwargs):
        if self.request.user.userprofile.Isclubmem:
            if self.request.method == 'POST':
                self.request.user.userprofile.userphoto = self.request.FILES.get('image')
                self.request.user.userprofile.phone_number = self.request.POST.get('userphonenumber')
                self.request.user.userprofile.Isclubmem = True
                club_member = Clubmember.objects.create(
                    user = self.request.user.userprofile,
                    refer = refgen(),
                )
                club_member.save()
                self.request.user.userprofile.save()
                return redirect('core:home')
        else:
            return redirect('/paytmpay')
```

Answer (score 0):

In you view there are no `Clubmember` named object passed to your render. Instead you have `club_member`.

club.html

```html
        <div class='container'>
            <p class="newlycreated">Prisimax Welcomes you {{user.username}}
            <img src={{user.userprofile.userphoto.url}} id="ownimg"></p>
            <br>
            <p style="margin-left: 100px;">Your LEVEL: {{club_member.level}} </p>
            <p style="margin-left: 100px;">Your cash <i class="fas fa-wallet"></i> : {{club_member.usermoney}}</p>
        </div>
```

Besides, you are using `template_name = "club.html"` variable but not using in your view. You should either delete this variable or use it in your code:

```py
            ...
            return render(self.request, self.template_name, context=context)
        return render(self.request, self.template_name)
```

Furthermore, the naming `self.request.user.userprofile.Isclubmem` is not good. You need to checkout python naming conventions aka PEP8.